# How to split a received string into DIVs that represent an A4 page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a long string that has styles through out it. Example:

```
This is a <b>bolded</b> word.
```

This needs to be sliced into smaller strings that would fit on an A4 page.
I need to accurately represent a long string over multiple A4 pages.
These DIVs are scaled down to fit on the screen of the device.

[image: Image represetation]

I don't have a list of different approaches that I have used before, because I don't even know where to start.

I can say that with the previous version of the application, the text was split into `div`s and then I would just get the `elementFromPoint()` that would be overflowing to the next page.

The style of the pages is correct, I just need to know when to separate the text.

Comment: Do you need it to be `A4` printable (300dpi), or just viewable (72dpi)?

Comment: It needs to be both, Reflecting for what it would look like printed aswell as be able to print, though the print functionality works already. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: In the code I've written above, you can edit `a4Height`. `595` = `72dpi` & `2480` = `300dpi`. `300+ dpi` is also know as printable resolution.

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: No problem! Much obliged. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution to your question.

I have used `jQuery` so don't forget to add:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your `<head>` tag.

The code requires `3 parameters`:

1. `String` - Your long string
2. `Height` - in `px` of the A4 page (set to `72dpi`).
3. `elemTag` - Parent div you want to contain all the page divs. I set it to `body` in this example.

Here is the code:

---

```js
// elemTag can be ID, Class or Tag
// Use to define where to append divs
function splitStringIntoDivs(string, height, elemTag) {
 let page = 0;
  var l, i = 0,
    arr = longString.split(' '),
    elem = $('<div data-page="' + page + '"/>').appendTo(elemTag);
  for (l = arr.length; l > i; i++) {
    elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
    if (elem.height() > a4Height) {
     page++;
      elem = $('<div data-page="' + page + '"/>').appendTo(elemTag);
      elem.append(arr[i] + ' ');
    }
  }
}

// 72dpi
var a4Width = 595;
var a4Height = 842;

var longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, volutpat purus a vitae id felis, diam amet nulla quis volutpat phasellus, ipsum nullam id non auctor diam adipiscing. Malesuada sem arcu arcu odio, nascetur sed, erat justo morbi ullamcorper dolor neque gravida, eget aliquet nibh felis wisi placeat magnis. Justo faucibus. Natus sollicitudin. Nonummy ut nisl lectus, natoque ad suspendisse, sit quam cras neque diam, in etiam ut aliquam curabitur consequat. Eu proin rerum urna, a eros turpis ipsum, turpis nibh vestibulum sed fusce turpis in. Fermentum gravida donec nulla lobortis consequat, ante volutpat ac vitae consequatur suspendisse nisl, et sed curabitur sem nam nonummy, nec dictum pede velit tristique quam blandit. Euismod ut et ac dictum id aliquam, euismod metus nec sit. Quis dignissim nonummy scelerisque nam, commodo amet at, nec semper risus. Aliquam blandit venenatis accumsan egestas erat orci.Consequat feugiat sed quisque in venenatis, phasellus feugiat, semper felis vivamus ultricies luctus et. Magnis in fames, elit lorem, mattis arcu congue quibusdam habitant tincidunt dolor, nullam feugiat imperdiet sapien blandit lacus, ut ultricies in morbi nulla mauris maecenas. Mi deserunt odio. Ante quam mus est tellus arcu. Elit dictumst, ut morbi non at tristique non suspendisse. Enim mauris ac, sem lorem libero quis odio odio dictum, in mauris posuere viverra, dui suscipit. Vitae enim in sapien. Turpis laborum et, id vitae vestibulum curabitur, cras pulvinar, id pulvinar sagittis dolor semper, at luctus mattis blandit amet. Nulla justo vitae aenean amet. In mi risus mattis.Voluptatem sed quisque molestie mattis facilis. Imperdiet ante vivamus turpis, nibh neque nulla asperiores. Erat ipsum mattis dolor enim aliquet nec, leo pellentesque vulputate nec vehicula. Dui facilisi sed eget, nulla ut eu quis sem. Mauris velit netus molestie quis dolor, massa vitae hac ut, luctus duis donec orci eu, ac aliquam tellus. Tempus netus cursus suscipit in non, nulla nam enim nulla nulla dignissim. Facilisi temporibus hac, ut dolor et cursus eros nam. Posuere nec diam faucibus, sit rhoncus primis, eros eros volutpat sapien eget. Dui urna interdum viverra id, id quam. Pulvinar dolor dolor ut donec mi.Feugiat luctus bibendum vivamus, lacus amet consequat aenean ornare urna, aliquam elementum lorem. Vulputate torquent nec fusce nec proin, ac lobortis per volutpat quis, id in in, lorem velit. Sed nec quam eget, cras lorem. Mi eu eu erat lacus feugiat, blandit quis ut donec. Tortor libero sed sit vitae, lectus in mollis et erat at. Maecenas mauris vestibulum eu, vestibulum mi maecenas laoreet. Non augue diam natoque orci, at eu facilisis ac id donec vel, id ad fusce fusce, interdum a habitasse. Auctor mauris est quam etiam magna arcu, neque augue nibh nonummy sed nulla quisque. Et mollit. Sed conubia enim. Porta scelerisque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, volutpat purus a vitae id felis, diam amet nulla quis volutpat phasellus, ipsum nullam id non auctor diam adipiscing. Malesuada sem arcu arcu odio, nascetur sed, erat justo morbi ullamcorper dolor neque gravida, eget aliquet nibh felis wisi placeat magnis. Justo faucibus. Natus sollicitudin. Nonummy ut nisl lectus, natoque ad suspendisse, sit quam cras neque diam, in etiam ut aliquam curabitur consequat. Eu proin rerum urna, a eros turpis ipsum, turpis nibh vestibulum sed fusce turpis in. Fermentum gravida donec nulla lobortis consequat, ante volutpat ac vitae consequatur suspendisse nisl, et sed curabitur sem nam nonummy, nec dictum pede velit tristique quam blandit. Euismod ut et ac dictum id aliquam, euismod metus nec sit. Quis dignissim nonummy scelerisque nam, commodo amet at, nec semper risus. Aliquam blandit venenatis accumsan egestas erat orci.Consequat feugiat sed quisque in venenatis, phasellus feugiat, semper felis vivamus ultricies luctus et. Magnis in fames, elit lorem, mattis arcu congue quibusdam habitant tincidunt dolor, nullam feugiat imperdiet sapien blandit lacus, ut ultricies in morbi nulla mauris maecenas. Mi deserunt odio. Ante quam mus est tellus arcu. Elit dictumst, ut morbi non at tristique non suspendisse. Enim mauris ac, sem lorem libero quis odio odio dictum, in mauris posuere viverra, dui suscipit. Vitae enim in sapien. Turpis laborum et, id vitae vestibulum curabitur, cras pulvinar, id pulvinar sagittis dolor semper, at luctus mattis blandit amet. Nulla justo vitae aenean amet. In mi risus mattis.Voluptatem sed quisque molestie mattis facilis. Imperdiet ante vivamus turpis, nibh neque nulla asperiores. Erat ipsum mattis dolor enim aliquet nec, leo pellentesque vulputate nec vehicula. Dui facilisi sed eget, nulla ut eu quis sem. Mauris velit netus molestie quis dolor, massa vitae hac ut, luctus duis donec orci eu, ac aliquam tellus. Tempus netus cursus suscipit in non, nulla nam enim nulla nulla dignissim. Facilisi temporibus hac, ut dolor et cursus eros nam. Posuere nec diam faucibus, sit rhoncus primis, eros eros volutpat sapien eget. Dui urna interdum viverra id, id quam. Pulvinar dolor dolor ut donec mi.Feugiat luctus bibendum vivamus, lacus amet consequat aenean ornare urna, aliquam elementum lorem. Vulputate torquent nec fusce nec proin, ac lobortis per volutpat quis, id in in, lorem velit. Sed nec quam eget, cras lorem. Mi eu eu erat lacus feugiat, blandit quis ut donec. Tortor libero sed sit vitae, lectus in mollis et erat at. Maecenas mauris vestibulum eu, vestibulum mi maecenas laoreet. Non augue diam natoque orci, at eu facilisis ac id donec vel, id ad fusce fusce, interdum a habitasse. Auctor mauris est quam etiam magna arcu, neque augue nibh nonummy sed nulla quisque. Et mollit. Sed conubia enim. Porta scelerisque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, volutpat purus a vitae id felis, diam amet nulla quis volutpat phasellus, ipsum nullam id non auctor diam adipiscing. Malesuada sem arcu arcu odio, nascetur sed, erat justo morbi ullamcorper dolor neque gravida, eget aliquet nibh felis wisi placeat magnis. Justo faucibus. Natus sollicitudin. Nonummy ut nisl lectus, natoque ad suspendisse, sit quam cras neque diam, in etiam ut aliquam curabitur consequat. Eu proin rerum urna, a eros turpis ipsum, turpis nibh vestibulum sed fusce turpis in. Fermentum gravida donec nulla lobortis consequat, ante volutpat ac vitae consequatur suspendisse nisl, et sed curabitur sem nam nonummy, nec dictum pede velit tristique quam blandit. Euismod ut et ac dictum id aliquam, euismod metus nec sit. Quis dignissim nonummy scelerisque nam, commodo amet at, nec semper risus. Aliquam blandit venenatis accumsan egestas erat orci.Consequat feugiat sed quisque in venenatis, phasellus feugiat, semper felis vivamus ultricies luctus et. Magnis in fames, elit lorem, mattis arcu congue quibusdam habitant tincidunt dolor, nullam feugiat imperdiet sapien blandit lacus, ut ultricies in morbi nulla mauris maecenas. Mi deserunt odio. Ante quam mus est tellus arcu. Elit dictumst, ut morbi non at tristique non suspendisse. Enim mauris ac, sem lorem libero quis odio odio dictum, in mauris posuere viverra, dui suscipit. Vitae enim in sapien. Turpis laborum et, id vitae vestibulum curabitur, cras pulvinar, id pulvinar sagittis dolor semper, at luctus mattis blandit amet. Nulla justo vitae aenean amet. In mi risus mattis.Voluptatem sed quisque molestie mattis facilis. Imperdiet ante vivamus turpis, nibh neque nulla asperiores. Erat ipsum mattis dolor enim aliquet nec, leo pellentesque vulputate nec vehicula. Dui facilisi sed eget, nulla ut eu quis sem. Mauris velit netus molestie quis dolor, massa vitae hac ut, luctus duis donec orci eu, ac aliquam tellus. Tempus netus cursus suscipit in non, nulla nam enim nulla nulla dignissim. Facilisi temporibus hac, ut dolor et cursus eros nam. Posuere nec diam faucibus, sit rhoncus primis, eros eros volutpat sapien eget. Dui urna interdum viverra id, id quam. Pulvinar dolor dolor ut donec mi.Feugiat luctus bibendum vivamus, lacus amet consequat aenean ornare urna, aliquam elementum lorem. Vulputate torquent nec fusce nec proin, ac lobortis per volutpat quis, id in in, lorem velit. Sed nec quam eget, cras lorem. Mi eu eu erat lacus feugiat, blandit quis ut donec. Tortor libero sed sit vitae, lectus in mollis et erat at. Maecenas mauris vestibulum eu, vestibulum mi maecenas laoreet. Non augue diam natoque orci, at eu facilisis ac id donec vel, id ad fusce fusce, interdum a habitasse. Auctor mauris est quam etiam magna arcu, neque augue nibh nonummy sed nulla quisque. Et mollit. Sed conubia enim. Porta scelerisque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, volutpat purus a vitae id felis, diam amet nulla quis volutpat phasellus, ipsum nullam id non auctor diam adipiscing. Malesuada sem arcu arcu odio, nascetur sed, erat justo morbi ullamcorper dolor neque gravida, eget aliquet nibh felis wisi placeat magnis. Justo faucibus. Natus sollicitudin. Nonummy ut nisl lectus, natoque ad suspendisse, sit quam cras neque diam, in etiam ut aliquam curabitur consequat. Eu proin rerum urna, a eros turpis ipsum, turpis nibh vestibulum sed fusce turpis in. Fermentum gravida donec nulla lobortis consequat, ante volutpat ac vitae consequatur suspendisse nisl, et sed curabitur sem nam nonummy, nec dictum pede velit tristique quam blandit. Euismod ut et ac dictum id aliquam, euismod metus nec sit. Quis dignissim nonummy scelerisque nam, commodo amet at, nec semper risus. Aliquam blandit venenatis accumsan egestas erat orci.Consequat feugiat sed quisque in venenatis, phasellus feugiat, semper felis vivamus ultricies luctus et. Magnis in fames, elit lorem, mattis arcu congue quibusdam habitant tincidunt dolor, nullam feugiat imperdiet sapien blandit lacus, ut ultricies in morbi nulla mauris maecenas. Mi deserunt odio. Ante quam mus est tellus arcu. Elit dictumst, ut morbi non at tristique non suspendisse. Enim mauris ac, sem lorem libero quis odio odio dictum, in mauris posuere viverra, dui suscipit. Vitae enim in sapien. Turpis laborum et, id vitae vestibulum curabitur, cras pulvinar, id pulvinar sagittis dolor semper, at luctus mattis blandit amet. Nulla justo vitae aenean amet. In mi risus mattis.Voluptatem sed quisque molestie mattis facilis. Imperdiet ante vivamus turpis, nibh neque nulla asperiores. Erat ipsum mattis dolor enim aliquet nec, leo pellentesque vulputate nec vehicula. Dui facilisi sed eget, nulla ut eu quis sem. Mauris velit netus molestie quis dolor, massa vitae hac ut, luctus duis donec orci eu, ac aliquam tellus. Tempus netus cursus suscipit in non, nulla nam enim nulla nulla dignissim. Facilisi temporibus hac, ut dolor et cursus eros nam. Posuere nec diam faucibus, sit rhoncus primis, eros eros volutpat sapien eget. Dui urna interdum viverra id, id quam. Pulvinar dolor dolor ut donec mi.Feugiat luctus bibendum vivamus, lacus amet consequat aenean ornare urna, aliquam elementum lorem. Vulputate torquent nec fusce nec proin, ac lobortis per volutpat quis, id in in, lorem velit. Sed nec quam eget, cras lorem. Mi eu eu erat lacus feugiat, blandit quis ut donec. Tortor libero sed sit vitae, lectus in mollis et erat at. Maecenas mauris vestibulum eu, vestibulum mi maecenas laoreet. Non augue diam natoque orci, at eu facilisis ac id donec vel, id ad fusce fusce, interdum a habitasse. Auctor mauris est quam etiam magna arcu, neque augue nibh nonummy sed nulla quisque. Et mollit. Sed conubia enim. Porta scelerisque."

splitStringIntoDivs(longString, a4Height, "body");
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, you can access the pages via e.g. `$('div').data("page", "0");`

Comment: This seems like it will work, I have implement a bit of the code and looks like I can get this working. It currently takes around 20 ms to run through 10 000 words. Thank you for your answer.